# Is there a way to somehow "isolate" a voltage drop?

Tags: batteries, resistance, load, voltage

I have a small issue with voltage drop. I'm working on a project, where I have five resistive wires (approx. 8 ohms each) connected to li-ion battery pack in parallel. The battery pack outputs 16.8V when fully charged (4S pack, max output current 7.65A). It is powering those 5 resistive wires in parallel, one arduino and DC motor.

My problem is caused by the voltage drop produced by those resistive wires. It is so significant that the battery pack can't power the motor any more (requires 12V). Is there some way to eliminate this, without adding one more battery pack or any other power source?

My cells: https://eu.nkon.nl/eve-inr18650-26v-2550mah-7-65a.html

Comment: If you are loading a 16.8 V pack to the point that you are getting less than 12 V at its terminals then you are overloading it. One more battery pack is not the solution. You need numbers to answer this question. In particular the battery specifications and your five heater resistances. [Edit] them into your question.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully fixed by now :-) !

Comment: Those cells are rated at 7.65 A but you haven't told us what the load current is. Again, what is the resistance of each heater?

Comment: I am sorry but I probably do not understand. Resistance of each heater is 8 ohms. The current drawn from the battery pack is 5.5A at most. So I am not exceeding the specs of those cells. Or am I missing something?

Comment: From Ohm's law, I = V/R = 16 / 8 = 2 A per heater X 5 = 10 A.

Comment: Ok, got the point. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129755/discussion-between-papouc-and-transistor).

Comment: Can you add a schematic of your setup? Are the Arduino and DC motor also in parallel with those wires?

Comment: As other mention 5x8ohms is too much load for this batt. pack. The solution can be a batt. pack with higher I capability, wires with higher resistances, wires connected in series (if reduced current/power is acceptable), driving the wires with PWM (also reduces power).

Comment: Ok, I temporarily dumped the battery pack (just for testing purposes). I replaced with variable power supply. But still, no matter what voltage I set, the voltage drop occurs. Even with 5 volts it falls down to about 2.8V. Why is that? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Ohm's Law in application.

The battery has an internal resistance, so when current flows, the voltage at the terminals will be less than the battery voltage.  Less current, less internal voltage drop.  You have 5 8Ω resistors in parallel.  Equivalent resistance is 1.6Ω

You get 12V at terminals, which means current is 7.5A (**max output current 7.65A**).

Internal resistance is:

$$r_s = \frac {E - V_{term}}{I_L} =  \frac {16.8V - 12V}{7.5A} = 0.64Ω$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5FzB1m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your options are to get a bigger capacity battery (more Ah to get you more A) or eliminate one or more of the resistive wires.

Comment: Thanks, best and most clear answer to me!! Appreciate your help!

Comment: Once you provide the measurements, the rest is easy!

Answer (score 1):

What is a "resistive wire" in your own terms? All conductors are resistive at some extent. Copper conductors and even gold wires have some milli Ohms of resistance per metre. If the gauge of your wire is not the adequate you wil run into overheating issues and power losses.

As @Transistor said, if your load is too high you will inevitably run into power delivery issues.

Have you measured the current that your load takes with an ammeter? Do that at the output of the batteries and choose the right wiring gauge and proper connectors (consider high current ones like XT connectors). Also, consider adding some power distribution electronics to manage your load's current and voltage needs.

Special attention is required when inductive loads, like motors, are used. For that you should consider PWM and switching MOSFETS for controlling the current delivery to them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so you think that my problem is caused by having insufficient wiring?

Comment: Your problem is too much load!

Comment: Improving the wiring would lower the resistance further and increase the load on the battery making the situation worse.

Answer (score 1):

### Your ohm data may be wrong

The problem is, lots of things are actually non-linear.

They give one resistance measurement when they are cold and quiescent. But in operation their resistance is quite different.  An incandescent bulb is a great example.  Its resistance is much lower when off than when on.

I would suggest disconnecting all but 1 of your heating strips, so you are not overloading the battery, then test it singly.

Place an ammeter inline in the circuit, and measure loop current. Meanwhile, measure voltage drop across the wire.  These are real live measurements in actual operation.    Now, solve for *actual, operating* resistance by plugging in your measured V and I and solving for R.

I bet you get an R *other than the one you were expecting*, and it explains everything.

Comment: I will definitley try!! Thanks for your time!!

Comment: But one more theoretical?? Isn't the resistance supposed to increase when the resistor gets hot? Which should result in current decrease.

Comment: I disconnected all wires except one and still ended up on same results. The circuit with one wire connected has resistance of 12.8 ohms - the measured current flowing is 1.29A. Voltage goes down about 0.2V at the battery terminals. Thanks for your advice anyway!